# Auto select the search bar when user enters the page, so he/she can type right away?

Tags: search

Basically, I want to do the same thing as Google does. I want to place the user's cursor into the search box as soon as he/she enters the site.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jQuery, and use somehting like this:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#search_field').focus();
});
```

It is also possible doing it in pure HTML 5 using the autofocus attribute, like that:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autofocus="autofocus" />
```